# Sencha Cmd side by side installation

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I need to build different Ext Js projects with different Ext Js framework versions. They also need different versions of Sencha Cmd for building (3.0.2.288 and 3.1.2.342). Generally it is possible to install two versions of Sencha Cmd side by side.

Do you think it is save to run multiple versions of Sencha Cmd side by side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the [advanced Cmd documentation, section "Multiple Installed Versions"](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/command_advanced). One can install multiple Sencha Cmd version side by side, AND Sencha Cmd will also try to use the correct version depending on the project. So, its a documentated feature!